# Regex for integer followed by single character

Tags: java, regex, mvel

Can anyone please let me know the regex code to enter digit(1 to 31) followed by one single character for example: 2d or 3d. The character will always remain 'd' or 'D' and number can be any number from 1 to 31. Basically this denotes 2 days or 3 days.

Comment: An easy enough task. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

### StackOverflow is not a homework service.

But here you go...

```
\b(?:3[01]|[12][0-9‌​]|[1-9])[dD]\b
```

You can use http://regexr.com to test out regular expressions easily.

(Improved by Biffen)

Comment: I'm pretty bad with regex and tend to avoid it so this definitely isn't the best example. I just provided something that works. Will fix and add disclaimer. :)

Comment: This can be shortened to `\b(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9])[dD]\b`.